# How to convert shapefile of India into a system with longitude and latitude system?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, india

I have two shapefiles of India. One is without PoK and other is with Pok. I want to convert the shapefile of India with PoK into a co-ordinate system with longitude and latitude (same as without PoK). I have tried in R, but could not crack the problem.

Here are the files for [Without PoK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7TdGA0qFbykVzkzVnlQREM1cTA/view?usp=sharing) and [With PoK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7TdGA0qFbykQm1JdWdtYWxKT2c/view?usp=sharing) India?

Comment: What is PoK? (projected coordinate system?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Without PoK" data is a shapefile that has been converted from an image. The shapefile extents are (0,0) and (1496,1497) which represent the cell/pixel sizes of the original image.

[image: Extract of rasterized India boundary data]

If you have the original image, you could try georeferencing it directly to your other data. Otherwise, you could try using the Spatial Adjustment toolbar, again to georeference it against your other data. Because the boundaries are very thick, georeferencing the original image may be easier.